# Why Doesn't Fiddler Show Curl Traffic?

Tags: windows, ssl, curl, proxy, fiddler

Why doesn't Fiddler show `curl` traffic? Other traffic gets displayed, just not `curl`. How can I get fiddler to intercept `curl` traffic?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Fiddler will not intercept curl traffic by default. You'll need to specify the `-x` proxy option. If curl displays an SSL error message, additionally use the `-k` option to disable SSL validation.

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8888 -k www.example.com
```

Comment: Very Helpful - Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to get curl to trust the Fiddler root cert?

Comment: @user24601 See [How to trust self-signed certificate in cURL command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451207/how-to-trust-self-signed-certificate-in-curl-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

In Telerik Fiddler Classic, use

```
curl --url example.com -x 127.0.0.1.8888 --ssl-no-revoke
```